# define function with memfn

Tags: macros, clojure

I'm working on some java library wrapper.
We have some object with methods and can invoke them with `(.method object ...)`. I want to create more convenient api with number of functions `(method object ...)`.

I wrote a simple macro:

```
(defmacro ^{:private true} gen-method [method & argv]
  `(def ~method (memfn ~method ~@argv)))
```

Now I can invoke `(gen-method charAt i)` for example and after that I can use `(charAt "string" 1)`.

But I have a lot of method to generate and want to use something like:

```
(map #(gen-method (-> %1 name symbol arg)) [:charAt :substring ...])
```

But this is not working. Next example is not working too:

```
(map #(let [fname (-> %1 name symbol)] (gen-method fname arg)) [:charAt :substring ...])
```

What I need to change in macro or add something for correct behaviour ?

Thanks.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Do you get an error message?

Comment: `arg` is just a symbol.  
can be what ever - it will be plased in `memfn`

Comment: As @OpenSauce asked, would you state the exact problem you are having?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to take the `map` operation inside the macro itself as the `map` operation should happen at compile time i.e form expanding time and not at runtime.

Something like below:

```
(defmacro ^{:private true} gen-methods [methods]
`(do 
       ~@(map (fn [[x & i]] (let [m (-> x name symbol)] `(def ~m (memfn ~m ~@i)) )) methods)))

(gen-methods [ [:charAt i] [:substring i]])
```

Comment: You're my hero.  
Made some corrections:  
    
    (defmacro ^{:private true} gen-method [& methods]
      `(do ~@(map
        (fn [[x & i]]
          (let [m (-> x name symbol)]
            `(def ~m (memfn ~m ~@i))))
        methods)))